# Invisible changes when screen update

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I'm new in react-native and have some probems. In the fahterScreen I add some items to array and pass to childs as prop, I need that the child (CanastaScreen) update every 1seg and show the new value. I have the next code:

```
export default class CanastaScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    setInterval( () => { this.render(); }, 1000);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          {this.props.screenProps.canasta.map( (item) => {
            console.log(item.nombre);
            return (
              <Text>{item.nombre}</Text>
            );
          })}
        </Content>
     </Container>
     );
  }
}
```

Console output show correctly:
Item1
Item2
Item3
etc.
But the screen is always in blank. Some can help my about it ?
Thanks

Comment: I strongly believe you have some styling problems.

Comment: @10101010 Can you show me the correct form to styling it ?

Comment: Is anything even rendering with a simple <Text> component with hard coded text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you never should call render method of a component. in React Native, a component should update only if it's state changes. so if you have something like this :

```
<Parent>
   <Canasta> ... </Canasta>
</Parent>
```

assuming that the changing variable is called `foo` in state of Parent, you need to pass it as prop to `Canasta` (child) and now by changing state of Parent (changing `foo`), `Canasta` should get updated. here's an example (calling updateFoo will update both `Parent` and `Canasta`):

```
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props); // it's recommended to include this in all constructors
      this.state = { foo: initalValue } // give some value to foo
   }
   updateFoo(newValue){
     this.setState({foo: newValue}) // setting state on a component will update it (as i said)
   }
   render() {
     return(
       <Canasta someProp={this.state.foo}> ... </Canasta>
     )
   }
}
}
```

Comment: React-native detect push in array as a update ? or I need to do 'this.setState( foo = foo.slice() )' ?

Comment: @faanbece just by calling setState, react native updates the components (re-render the data changes) and it doesn't really matter  what new value is given to state.

Comment: Oh, perfect, its alive ! thank you very much friend. :-)

Comment: @faanbece you're welcome. please mark this as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After various changes, is found, the complete structure is: Parent(App.js) call children(Menu, Canasta). Menu allow add items to the shop-car and Canasta allow to sort and delete items. These are the important parts of the code:

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.stateUpdater = this.stateUpdater.bind(this);
    this.state = { canasta:[] };
  }

render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <RootNavigation data={[this.state, this.stateUpdater]} />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

**Menu.js**

```
  tryAddCanasta(index, plato){
      let canasta = this.props.screenProps[0].canasta;
      plato.id_Plato = canasta.length;
      canasta.push(plato);
      this.props.screenProps[1]('canasta', canasta);
  }
```

**Canasta.js**

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return true;
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <List>
            {this.props.screenProps[0].canasta.map( (item) => {
               return ( this._renderRow(item) );
             })}
          </List>
       </Content>
     </Container>
     );
  }
```

Special thanks to **@Shadow_m2**, now I don't need check every time, it works in "real time"